# How many plpython execution environments are opened in a query?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, greenplum, plpython

Are user defined functions in postgres (and greenplum) run in isolation?
How many execution environments are open when I have a query with a plpythonu user-defined functions?
Is there any shared python interpreter state when running a query?

Say I have a plpython user defined function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file2text(path string) RETURNS text AS $$
    f = open(path, 'r')
    return f.read()
    f.close()
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

For a table `create table files (name varchar, path varchar)` and a query over that table as follows:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM files f
WHERE character_length( file2text(f.path) ) > 4096
ORDER BY f.name
```

Is a new python environment spawned for each execution of my plpython function? 
In a MPP databases, can I assume that the behavior of postgres be duplicated across each segment with no shared state across segments?

Answer (score 4):

PL/Python state is isolated between sessions, and shared within a session.

You can test that pretty easily by placing a variable in the `sys` module (for testing only!) or better, in a custom module you import. You should see that the variable is visible to other functions that run within the same session (connection), but not to functions in other sessions.